# Threading issue in hashmap

Tags: java, multithreading

I am using two threads to put values in the same hashmap. Thread 1 will read the values what it was stored and thread 2 will read only the values what it was stored in the map.

In that i am getting `NullPointerException`. Is that due to threading issue??

```
HashMap map = new HashMap();

    Thread1:

           map.put(1,1);
           map.put(2,2);
           map.get(1).toString(); // here null pointer i am getting.. Is it possible due to threading issue..

    Thread 2:
       map.put(4,4);
       map.put(5,5)
```

Comment: I don't see it can return `null` with posted code in any scenario, please add code which can reproduce this error

Comment: Please append your whole source code and Exception stacktrace, mind reading has not been invented.

Comment: I am getting the error in my production environment.. And i am having more java files..

Comment: Short answer: yes. `HashMap` isn't inherently thread-safe, so modifying it from two different threads may lead to unexpected results. [Use the right tool for the job](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html)

Answer (score 3):

There are 2 solutions

1) Use java.util.ConcurrentHashMap, which is designed to operate in a threaded enviornment.

2) Synchronize the hashmap.  Java allows you to synchronize on objects, so you can ensure that only one thread touches the object at at time.

ex.

```
synchronized(map) {
    map.put("important", "stuff");
}
```

Method #2 is NOT the preferred solution for multithreading (CuncurrentHashMap is), but is your only option if you cannot change the type of the variable (like on a large project).

Answer (score 2):

@Dylan is correct, short answer is you should never use HashMaps in a concurrent environment.  Luckily, java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap to the rescue.

Comment: Yes... I dont want to use ConcurrentHashMap. This is to avoid locking overhead.

Comment: The ConcurrentHashMap does a very good job of avoiding locking overhead if at all possible.  It locks portions of the Map, not the whole thing.  If you optimize the size of the CHM and carefully design it (setting load factor and currency level well), you should have a very low collision rate.